# Typescript - Property with default value is undefined

Tags: typescript, oop

```
export class EntityVM implements EntityModel {
  ...
  Properties...
  ...
  constructor(newEntity: EntityModel, isCollapsed = false) {
    ...
    Properties...
    ...
    this.isCollapsed = isCollapsed;
  }
}

public myFunction(myEntity: EntityVM) {
  //!! here myEntity.isCollapsed is undefined instead of false
}

public myEntity = new Array<EntityModel>();

myFunction(myEntity)
```

When converting from **EntityModel** to **EntityVM** it does not add **isCollapsed** to false.

Comment: You're passing an array to `myFunction` and arrays do not have an `isCollapsed` field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code, you are use wrong syntax,
it should be:

```
class EntityModel {}

export class EntityVM implements EntityModel {
  public isCollapsed;
  constructor(newEntity: EntityModel, isCollapsed = false) {
    this.isCollapsed = isCollapsed;
  }
}
// public myEntity = new Array<EntityModel>() // please note, that `Array` is not your class.
// you should be aware of it that typing dont have impact or value on runtime.
const myEntity = new EntityVM({});

function myFunction(myEntity: EntityVM) {
  console.log(myEntity); // => will print Class EntityVM
  //!! myEntity will have default value now
}

myFunction(myEntity);
```

For better understanding, here the sandbox you can see: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-tqirps?file=index.ts

I hope it helps!

Comment: Thank you for the simplification of my example. Thus what I wanted to understand was how typescript converts the EntityModel object to a EntityVM one when is passed through the function.
In your example you have changed
`const myEntity = new EntityModel({});`
to
`const myEntity = new EntityVM({});`
I want to convert this object when entering the function and set it's default property to false.

Comment: I've checked on stackblitz. I thought that I can transform a base class object into it's child class and get the default values from the constructor. That was my idea. But apparently I cannot do that.

Comment: I see, so you intentionally create new EntityModel class, then pass it to myFunction.
maybe if you could put your codes inside the stackblitz i can help further what you want to achive?

Comment: There is no need. Thank you for the explanation!
It was something that I've seen at work during debugging of another bug. What was curios is that in our codebase it was not seen as a bug whereas stackblitz prevents you from running the code.

Comment: Lmao, alright then!